# (CLT) Number of rolls of two fair dice to be 90% certain that the percentage of times they show the same face is between 5/36 and 7/36

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice

> How often do you have to roll two fair six-sided dice to be 90% certain that the percentage of times they show the same face is between 5/36 and 7/36?

I was thinking, to apply the central limit theorem, between the two bounds, but I have no idea how to setup it.

**First of all thanks to Henry for your answer.**

> My professor said,
>
> **First :**
>
> From the statement of the problem one must know, how to apply the
>   correction factor to correctly have the limit in which one evaluate
>   the normal, and find the correct n.
>
> **Second:** The distribution is binomial and it will be impossible have a
>   greater value (%) for 486 than 487.

---

```
I have three question:

1) How Henry obtain (5/36n)^(1/2) for the standard deviation.
2) Where is my mistake evaluating the probability of 486 and 487.
3) How to solve it using the CLT.
```

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder whether by "correction" he meant a continuity correction?

Comment: Yes, he mean the continuity correction (The professor was not sure, he only told me that can not be true that point (2) is correct. That is why, I want to look a neat solution, to see if he is rigth or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a binomial distribution with parameter $p$ so the expectation of the number of same-faces is $\frac{n}{6}$ and variance $\frac{5n}{36}$.

For the proportion you have expectation $\frac{1}{6}$ and variance $\frac{5}{36n}$ so a standard deviation of $\sqrt{\frac{5}{36n}}$.

If you are going to use the central limit theorem, then since  $\Phi^{-1}(0.95)\approx 1.644854$ the symmetric two-tailed $90\%$ interval is $\pm 1.644854$ standard deviations from the mean.  So you want to find $n$ such that $\frac{1}{36} = 1.644854 \sqrt{\frac{5}{36n}}$, suggesting $n$ should be at least $486.9978$.  That is not quite an integer, so you will need to round up to $487$.

Curiously, while that is a good approximation, $487$ in fact fails, with a probability for the interval of about $0.8996$, while $486$ succeeds with a probability of about $0.90002$.

Assuming that your "between"  interval is inclusive (though that only matters when $n$ is a multiple of $36$), the exact values to ensure a $90\%$ probability using a binomial distribution seem to be $474, 475,479,480,481,482,484,485,486,489,494,495,496,499,500,$ and any larger numbers, but not $487$, taken from the R code:

```
n <- 1:600
intprob <- pbinom(7/36 * n, n, 1/6) - 
           pbinom(5/36 * n - 10^(-12), n, 1/6)
which(intprob >= 0.9)
```

Comment: a) When you said, " since Φ(0.95)≈1.644854Φ(0.95)≈1.644854 the symmetric two-tailed 90% interval is ±1.644854±1.644854 standard deviations from the mean"" Is it 0.95 must change for 90%?

Comment: b) To answer the question the # time to get that ptobability it is 474? the smaller amount. c) Are any way to use chebyshev's theorem and have the number in a quick way (no so much calculation). Thanks a lot, and I'm sorry if I ask silly questions.

Comment: @JulietaR: (a) With a normal distribution, the probability of being *above* $\Phi^{-1}(0.95)\approx 1.644854$ standard deviations *above* the mean is $5\%$.  Similarly the probability of being *below*  $1.644854$ standard deviations *below* the mean is $5\%$.  So the probability of being *within* $1.644854$ standard deviations of the mean is $90\%$, and that is how $\Phi^{-1}(0.95)$ is used to find a $90\%$ two-tailed interval.

Comment: @JulietaR: (b) If this is a school exercise then I suspect that the approximation $487$ is the desired answer.  All I was doing with the exact answer was demonstrating that this is indeed an approximation, and using a discrete calculation shows counter-intuitively that in a small range using a slightly larger sample size does not always increase the probability of being in the given interval, though the changes are small.

Comment: @JulietaR: Using Chebyshev's inequality will give a weak approximation as you will be looking to use $ \Pr(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$ so you want $\frac{1}{k^2} \le 1-0.9$  and $k\sigma = \frac1{36}$ with $\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{5}{36n}}$, leading to $n \ge 1800$, which is much higher than necessary.

Comment: I try to solve using CLT, and I have 487, but I can't fully understand why my professor said is not right that 487 fail and 486 works. ( :-) I belive far more in your answer than in the word of my proffessor told me).Thanks.